# Creating a loop of 12 hours in dataframe with timestamp index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, datetime, timestamp

```
df['index_day'] = df.index.floor('d')
```

my dataframe is `df.head`

```
                     index_day      P2_Qa  ...     P2_Qcon       P2_m
2019-01-10 17:00:00 2019-01-10  93.599342  ...  107.673342  14.962424
2019-01-10 17:01:00 2019-01-10  90.833884  ...  104.658384  14.343642
2019-01-10 17:02:00 2019-01-10  90.907001  ...  104.601001  14.568892
2019-01-10 17:03:00 2019-01-10  93.579973  ...  107.115473  14.884902
2019-01-10 17:04:00 2019-01-10  93.688072  ...  107.168072  14.831412
```

I'm looping for every day

```
for day, i in df.groupby('index_day'):
    sns.jointplot(x='P2_Tam', y='P2_Qa', data=i, kind='reg')
    j=j+1
    plt.savefig(j+'.png')
```

This gives me regression plots for one day 24 hours. However, I want such plots for nights only. Loop around 12 hours where `one night = one loop= 1 plot` from 18:00 till 6 in the morning morning.

However, i want to loop with `one loop = 18:00 till 6:00 of next day` rather than `one loop=24 hours of one day`. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you add some sample data [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to question?

Comment: Is it clear what I'm trying to do exactly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can filter first by [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) only for nights and then loop by `12H` with `base=6`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=35, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(35)}, index=rng)  

df = df.between_time('18:00:01', '6:00')
print (df)
                      a
2017-04-03 00:00:00   0
2017-04-03 01:00:00   1
2017-04-03 02:00:00   2
2017-04-03 03:00:00   3
2017-04-03 04:00:00   4
2017-04-03 05:00:00   5
2017-04-03 06:00:00   6
2017-04-03 19:00:00  19
2017-04-03 20:00:00  20
2017-04-03 21:00:00  21
2017-04-03 22:00:00  22
2017-04-03 23:00:00  23
2017-04-04 00:00:00  24
2017-04-04 01:00:00  25
2017-04-04 02:00:00  26
2017-04-04 03:00:00  27
2017-04-04 04:00:00  28
2017-04-04 05:00:00  29
2017-04-04 06:00:00  30
```

---

```
for i, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H', base=6, closed='right')):
    if not g.empty:
        print (g)

                     a
2017-04-03 00:00:00  0
2017-04-03 01:00:00  1
2017-04-03 02:00:00  2
2017-04-03 03:00:00  3
2017-04-03 04:00:00  4
2017-04-03 05:00:00  5
2017-04-03 06:00:00  6
                      a
2017-04-03 19:00:00  19
2017-04-03 20:00:00  20
2017-04-03 21:00:00  21
2017-04-03 22:00:00  22
2017-04-03 23:00:00  23
2017-04-04 00:00:00  24
2017-04-04 01:00:00  25
2017-04-04 02:00:00  26
2017-04-04 03:00:00  27
2017-04-04 04:00:00  28
2017-04-04 05:00:00  29
2017-04-04 06:00:00  30
```

EDIT:

If want select by 12 hours after start time one possible solution with [`DataFrame.truncate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=35, freq='2H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(35)}, index=rng)  

dates = df.index.floor('d').unique() 

for s, e in zip(dates + pd.Timedelta(18, unit='H'), 
                dates + pd.Timedelta(30, unit='H')):
    df1 = df.truncate(s, e)
    if not df1.empty:
        print (df1)


                      a
2017-04-03 18:00:00   9
2017-04-03 20:00:00  10
2017-04-03 22:00:00  11
2017-04-04 00:00:00  12
2017-04-04 02:00:00  13
2017-04-04 04:00:00  14
2017-04-04 06:00:00  15
                      a
2017-04-04 18:00:00  21
2017-04-04 20:00:00  22
2017-04-04 22:00:00  23
2017-04-05 00:00:00  24
2017-04-05 02:00:00  25
2017-04-05 04:00:00  26
2017-04-05 06:00:00  27
                      a
2017-04-05 18:00:00  33
2017-04-05 20:00:00  34
```

Comment: However, what if setting frequency is not an option? I'm doing night analysis of the data and during winter, nights are not exactly of 12 hours but longer here in Europe. So setting frequency 12H is not an option. I want to loop through data where one loop = 16 hours  from 16:00 till 8:00 of next date. What then? Thanks

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot. You're the unsung hero of StackOverflow. Cheers!! :)